# IntelliJ prevent two run configurations to run at the same time

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

I have two run configurations that start the same spring application. The difference is that one start some other run configurations and then start spring app and the other start only spring app.

Now I can start both of them but I would like to stop other automatically (if it is running) before starting selected one.

Maybe below structure will help in understanding my issue:

```
- SpringApp_RunConf1 
    1) start Other_RunConf and wait to finish
    2) start Spring application

- SpringApp_RunConf2
    1) Just start Spring application

- Other_RunConf
    1) start some other run configuration, do some maven job
```

So, if I start SpringApp_RunConf1 it shold stop SpringApp_RunConf2 if it is running.

Thanks for help!

Comment: This is not supported bu the IDE yet. You can vote and follow this request: [IDEA-234433](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234433).

Comment: Thank you Andrey, I voted and added a comment. Someone obviously have the same issue :)